# Sort points in vector to form conture

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, coordinates

I got a vector with n rows with xy coordinates of points. These points form a conture of an given CAD model. Now I want to restore the conture of the model. So I tried to sort the point with the atan2 function.
This is the code I use to sort the points.

```
std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), sort1);

matrix.erase(std::unique(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), compare2),matrix.end());

matrix.push_back(std::vector<double>(3, 0));
```

So first I sort the points in the vector matrix. As compare function i use this code

```
bool sort1(vector<double> const& s1, vector<double> const& s2)
{
    return atan2(s1[1],s1[0])<atan2(s2[1],s2[0]);
}
```

After the vector has been sorted, I just delete duplicates to reduce the size of the vector. The last step is to push back the first point to the end of the vector to close the conture.
For standard models like a cube, or a ball this works fine, but for more complicate models the atan2 function is note working fine.
So this image show the unsorted points.
[image: Picture of unsorted points]

When I sort the vector I get this conture as result
[image]

My first approach was to check the atan2 function but it's working fine. The problem seem to be the result of the atan2 function. So this list shows the actual coordinates and the result of the atan2 function

```
   x             y      z     atan2
-5.44283    -1.94995    0   -2.79758
-5.36969    -1.93228    0   -2.79617
-5.33637    -1.92454    0   -2.79547
-13.15      -4.76500    0   -2.79395
-5.26308    -1.90750    0   -2.79389
-5.22970    -1.90005    0   -2.7931
-5.15626    -1.88364    0   -2.79134
```

As you can see while the x and y coordinate change the atan2 stays in the same range as the other values. For me that's the problem, why my conture isn't correct. Do I have to add something to my sort function to get the correct results?

One idea i had was to sort the coordinates not just by the atan2, but also by the length of the vector between the point, with the lowest atan2, and all other points. But here's my problem. I would first sort by atan2, and then sort again by the length. But the second sort process would destroy the hole result of the first sort function.

Comment: So basically, atan2 is not the right way to sort and you want to know how to sort to get a contour for any given set of points. This seems to be more math related.

Comment: For me atan2 seems to be a good start to sort the vector. But I think I need more than just this one function to sort the whole vector.

Comment: atan2 performs a circular scan, which is okay for a limited set of points, not for more complex contours or contours where the origin is not inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atan2` obviously won't help in generic case. It is mostly good for convex figures. Consider a narrow rectangle with (0,0) inside and an adjacent rectangle and try to sort their points by their atan2.
Have you tried painting a point in the set and then looking for the closest not yet painted point as an iteration step?

Comment: So you mean i could start by sorting the vector by atan2, search the point with the lowest result and use this point as my new starting point. From this point on I would search for the nearest point and add it as the second in the vector and use this point again as my starting point. And the I would continue this till I get to the last point in the vector?

Comment: Sure, but sorting is totally unnecessary here (take an arbitrary point and rotate the coordinate axes so that it falls on the x axis, so its atan2 is 0; you can see, that sorting does not add anything here).

A more complicated algorithm involves backtracking: when you choose the next point but apparently moving to it changes the direction of velocity vector too radically (more than pi/2 is a good start), you probably have to move back a few points and try another way.

Comment: Finally, you can draw a closed contour through all your points as a start and then perform several optimization steps of making it less crooked: use the sum of absolute values of angular velocity changes at all points as the functional to be minimized, then try swapping neighboring vertices to see if it makes the functional's value less.

Comment: Even simpler, I think minimizing the polygon length will suffice, and not messing up with angles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with curves only then I'd suggest to use following algorithm:

1. Define angle range **R**
2. Take initial point **A**, mark it as visited
3. Find closest to **A** point **B**, mark it as visited
4. Calculate the direction formed by vector [**A**, **B**]
5. Find closest to **B** unvisited point **C** in angle range **R** and mark it visited
6. Go to step 4 with **B** as **A** and **C** as **B**

This is not an ultimate solution but it should be able to find basic curves and some polygons. With wider angle range **R** you can approximate more curved lines.